# SharePoint Enterprise & Yammer Licening

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, office-365, licensing, yammer

I have a user that owns SharePoint 2013 Enterprise.  I noticed there is an option for Yammer Configuration and to activate this feature.

Do they own Yammer and the ability to use it?  Or do they also need O365 and what are those costs?

They do not currently use O365 and its all on-premise currently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Yammer is separate. The price of a CAL depends totally on your situation .

If you want to use yammer in SharePoint on-premise, the following articles for your reference:

Integrate Yammer with on-premises SharePoint 2013

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WX-k7zDWUI

Integrate Yammer with on-premises SharePoint 2013 environments

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270535.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39357

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must have some form of licensing to Yammer, either just Yammer or via another packaged license like Office 365 E3.